# How to fast convert uniform random integer to floating point value with equal number of positive and negative values

Tags: c++

I can't do a simple cast since there's one more negative value than the positive values. To make it worse the min value has a larger abs value than the max value.
It dosen't matter if the value is the same as the original signed integer. It just needs to be equal number and min and max have the save abs value.

I come up with two ways but they are twice as slow as a simple cast (which is already slow)

```
double simple_cast(std::uint32_t u) {
  return (double)(std::int32_t)u; //biased
}

double symmetrical_cast_signed_mag(std::uint32_t u) {
  auto sign = u >> 31;
  auto val = (double)(u & 0x7fffffff);
  if (sign == 1) {
    return -val;
  }
  return val;
}

double symmetrical_cast_reject_min(std::uint32_t u) {
  auto i = (std::int32_t)u;
  if (i == std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (double)u;
}
```

You can assume all possible value the integer can represent is a possible input for the cast functions. And the result should be of type double and in range [-INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX]. (the result may still biased with two 0s, but it's fine)

Comment: Use `uniform_real_distribution`? What are the min and max values of your random integer?

Comment: Read this documentation : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/ on how to generate random numbers (in any kind of distribution). Don't use old style "rand()". Want to know why watch [All I wanted was a random number"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_QO1nm7uJs)

Comment: What makes you think `uniform_real_distribution` would have a slightly of a chance to be faster?

Comment: @W.H Are you asking me? I think it's just as fast as it can get to get a proper uniform distribution. Both `int` and `real` distributions have some overhead (state) to make that happen.

Comment: @TedLyngmo there's no way it can be faster since it needs to cater all possible input range and output range and needs to have no bias.

Comment: @W.H I said I think it will be as fast as it can be and still provide a proper uniform distribution. If you don't want that, you can take shortcuts.

Comment: Get something working correctly before worrying about speed

Comment: Fast and wrong is at best no better than too slow, and it can be a whole lot worse.

Comment: @TedLyngmo What I meant is I don't mind 0 has twice the chance to appear than the rest of the values, otherwise we have to go for the rejection approach (not the one in `symmetrical_cast_reject_min` since it doesn't actually reject anything, and the bias is still there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for the reject approach. In a tight loop, reject and regenerate is as fast as a direct type cast, because the rejection branch almost never happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `std::uniform_real_distribution` with the same input as you use for your `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

// A generator storing the result from another generator
template <class G>
struct shadow {
    using result_type = typename G::result_type;
    static constexpr result_type min() { return G::min(); }
    static constexpr result_type max() { return G::max(); }

    result_type operator()() { return val; }

    void operator()(G& g) {
        val = g();
    }

    result_type val;
};
```

Here I create two distributions with the same range. One `int` and one `real`

```
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> id(
        std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max());

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rd(
        id.min(),
        std::nextafter( // adjust for the half-open interval in real dists.
            static_cast<double>(id.max()),
            std::numeric_limits<double>::max()));
```

Then I call the `mt19937` generator once, store it in the my `shadow` and use the `shadow` as a generator for both distributions:

```
    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    shadow<std::mt19937> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        s(gen);           // generate and store the result in s
        auto idr = id(s); // integer result
        auto rdr = rd(s); // real result

        std::cout << idr << '\t' << rdr << '\n';
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4obvK7TTK)

If you want your real distribution to be equally distributed in the interval `[-INT_MAX, +INT_MAX]`, you can adjust the distribution by changing the minimum value of it:

```cpp
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rd(
        -id.max(), // instead of INT_MIN, -INT_MAX
        std::nextafter( // adjust for the half-open interval in real dists.
            static_cast<double>(id.max()),
            std::numeric_limits<double>::max()));
```

Comment: this could result in infinite loop. To get rid of bias, std::some_distribution needs to reject some values and re-generate a new one, if the cached value happens to be the one needs to be rejected, it would stuck in reject and re-generate loop forvere since shadow<...> keeps returning the same value.

Comment: @W.H The value it'll reject isn't static but depends on the input so the loop will get out of it - if I'm reading the source of the distributions correctly. `do __ret = __uctype(__urng()) - __urngmin;  while (__ret >= __past);`

Comment: Did you try to see if my suggested solution does the right thing? I can't say anything about the speed. Haven't checked.

Comment: I see only `__ret` is updated in the loop, and in this case it would be updated to the same value since `__urng()` returns the same cached value. which means `__ret >= __past` would stay the same, if i'm not mistaken. and this is just one implementation.

Comment: @W.H Yes, you are probably correct. That needs some investigation and possibly some adjustment to keep both distributions "happy" with the same generated result.

Comment: @W.H I just noticed that the clang version of the `int` and `real` distributions do not go hand-in-hand as nicely as gcc's version. It looks really odd.